# Background of div not changing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, nav

I have a navigation where the active boxes should be black and the non-active boxes are white however they all stay white. I'm trying to get it so that say you press the 4th box, all the boxes leading to the 4th would be coloured black.

[jsBin](http://jsbin.com/joxic/1/edit)

```
.nav__link--active .nav__link-bullet{
    -webkit-animation: bounce .40s linear;
    animation: bounce .40s linear;
    background-color: black;
}
```

It seems to be overridden by

```
.nav__link-bullet{
    display: block;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    background-color: white;
}
```

but I can't seem to get it to work right.

Answer (score 1):

In your javascript file, you have to define the `click` event of the nav elements to remove all `active` classes and make the `div` parent active

```
   $('.nav__link a').click(function(){
       $('.nav__link').removeClass('nav__link--active')
       $(this).parent().addClass('nav__link--active');

   })
```

Here is the example on <kbd>**[jsBin](http://jsbin.com/kutawaje/1/edit)**</kbd>

Comment: Is there any reason it works on codepen? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mLdto I can't replicate it outside of it.